# Establish the convergence and find the limits of the following sequence

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

$a_n = \left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}$

I know that the answer is supposed to be $e$ but I am unsure how to reach that answer.

I am so lost where to even begin with this

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** $a_n = \left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n\cdot \left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)$

Comment: Where would you go from here

Comment: From there, you go to my answer. That is what the hint is implying. Since $\lim (1+\frac{1}{n}) = 1$. You need only find the other factors limit.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I dont think there is any way to "prove" that:
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = e$$

At least, not without circular reasoning.

The fundamental problem is that this limit **IS THE** definition of Euler's Number.  This is how Jacob Bernoulli defined it.

All other properties (the ones that might be used to prove this) stem from the truth of this definition.

---

Im fairly confident that if you took the binomial expansion:
$$ \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^k$$
Then took the limit as $n\to\infty$, using, say, the Ratio Test or something, you should be able to prove convergence.

Actually, it might be easier to use the monotone convergence criterion. Let $s_n=(1+\frac1n)^n$ and you can easily show with inductive arguments both that the sequence increases and is bounded above by 3.

Then, simply declare that the limit is called $e$, which is what Bernoulli did.

Comment: how would you go about establishing the convergence

Comment: Im not sure how Bernoulli proved that the limit converged at all. I think the proof models the expression after the binomial expansion.

Answer (score 1):

$$(1)\ \lim_n a_n = \lim _n e^{\ (n+1)\cdot\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})} = e^{\lim \limits_n \ (n+1) \cdot \ln(1+\frac{1}{n})} = e^1$$

$\textbf{Comment}$: Verfify by L'H (or however you see fit) that, $$\lim_{n} \frac{\ln \big(1+ \frac{1}{n}\big)}{\frac{1}{(n+1)}} = \lim_{x} \bigg(\frac{1}{x(x+1)}\bigg)(x+1)^2 = \lim_{x} \frac{x+1}{x}=1.$$

$\textbf{Recall}$: From calculus that if $f(x)$ is a continuous function and $(a_n) \to L$ then $f(a_n) \to f(L)$. In this case $f(x)=e^x$ is our continuous function.

Comment: You are relying on the properties of $e$ to prove the definition of $e$ from which those properties emerge. Check out prior discussions.

Comment: Simply using the fact that $e^x, ln(x)$ are inverses of each other.

Comment: Thats not all youre using. Youve assumed the consequence: that $e$ exists, ie that the limit converges and has a value in the first place.  Substitute the $\ln$ and $e^x$ for the more generic inverses $\log_b$ and $b^x$ and you will hit a wall.  You will arrive at $$b^{\lim \log_b (1+1/n)^n}$$
With no way to evaluate the limit. You'll be stuck trying to prove what you started with.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$a_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}$$
$$\ln a_n=\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}$$
$$\ln a_n=(n+1) \ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$